# Unity Runtime Surface Snapping (Like Shift+Cntrl in Editor)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to allow the user of my VR game to move objects around using a pointer, then when holding down a button, snap to a grid and align to the highest surface, essentially replicating the Editor behavior or holding down shift+control and moving around a transform gizmo. (Try it, it's fun!)

I have the grid part down, but can't wrap my head around how to do the surface snapping.
Here is the code I have so far. I would appreciate any and all help!

```
 
// offsetPos is where the VR pointer is.
Vector3 offsetPos = pointer.objectControlPoint.transform.position + cursorOffset;
Vector3 newPos;
 
if (isSnapping) // Snap to ground code.
{
// I read previously to do this up then down thing, but It's not working as expected
    RaycastHit groundHit = new RaycastHit();
    if (Physics.Raycast(selectedObject.transform.position, Vector3.down, out groundHit))
    {
         RaycastHit objectHit = new RaycastHit();
         if (Physics.Raycast(groundHit.point, Vector3.up, out objectHit))
         {
                Vector3 snapDiff = groundHit.point - objectHit.point;
                snapYPos = snapDiff.y + (selectedObject.collider.bounds.extents.y);
          }
    }
      // worldGrid is a monoBehavior on another object, and gridCellSize is just a float
      float gridPosX = Mathf.Floor(offsetPos.x / worldGrid.gridCellSize) * worldGrid.gridCellSize;
      float gridPosZ = Mathf.Floor(offsetPos.z / worldGrid.gridCellSize) * worldGrid.gridCellSize;
      newPos = new Vector3(gridPosX, snapYPos, gridPosZ); // Sets the target position to the nearest grid cell, with a Y of the snap position.
}
else // If not in snap mode, set target position to just the VR cursor.
{
       newPos = new Vector3(offsetPos.x, offsetPos.y, offsetPos.z);
}
 
// I know lerp might not be the most efficient, but I like the smooth effect, and it looks good when snapping to the grid...
selectedObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(selectedObject.transform.position, newPos, movementLerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

The objects I need to be snapping all are different sizes and have their origins in different places, but all do have appropriate box colliders.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think [`Physics.ComputePenetration`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html) is what you are looking for. It allows to check whether two Colliders if placed at certain positions and orientations **would** overlap and returns additionally the direction and distance of the shortest translation necessary to separate them so they would not overlap anymore

Comment: @derHugo Good find!  Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to use this, and also follow the VR pointer's X and Z values.

Comment: Why don't you think so? You will need to define priorities: 1. Follow Cursor, 2. Snap to (away from) Surfaces then 3. Snap to the closest possible grid point (that lies in the opposite direction of the surface snap) after doing 1 and 2. Such that 3 won't snap again into the surface we just snapped away from

Comment: Ah now I get what you mean I think ... you mean if you have a quite high object it might rather snap around it then as desired onto the top of it ... Well .. couldn't you not just use the Box collider sizes and the center positions and from that calculate how much they overlap and move the object up accordingly?

Comment: @derHugo I'll be perfectly honest and say that you might have the right answer, but I'm totally lost about how to actually code it.  I'm not the best at positions, rotations, vectors, etc.  Any clarification or examples would be appreciated.  If not, no worries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly now and you actually just struggle at the correct value for `Y` I think you are actually almost there.

Except that currently you only get the delta between the two points on the Colliders. But you need to take into account also any offset between objects and their colliders. I'll try to illustrate it

```
 ---------
 |       |
 |  °    |
 |   x   |  -------
 |       |  |     |
 |       |  |  x  |
 ---------  | °   |
            -------
```

Let's say here `x` is the actual BoxCollider center and `°` is the actual object `transform.position`.

So assuming the objects are not rotated at all I would not go through the bounds but rather do

```
if (Physics.Raycast(selectedObject.transform.position, Vector3.down, out var groundHit))
{
    var groundCollider = groundHit.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    var groundTopY = groundHit.transform.TransformPoint(groundCollider.center + groundCollider.size * 0.5f).y;

    var selectedCollider = selectedObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    var selectedBottomY = selectedObject.transform.TransformPoint(selectedCollider.center - selectedCollider.size * 0.5f).y;
    var selectedCenterOffsetY = selectedObject.transform.TransformPoint(selectedCollider.center).y;

    snapYPos = groundTopY + (groundTopY - selectedBottomY) - selectedCenterOffsetY; 
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: is size the size of selectedObject's collider or the size of groundHit box collider?

Comment: @MidnightCoffee both actually ;) `groundCollider.size` and `selectedCollider.size`